# How can I output an array with a bunch of assignments from a folder of files?

Tags: java, file-io

I have 151 images I would like stored in an array that includes their file path and some attributes which will be String data extracted from the file names.

I am guessing I'll be using File IO/NIO for this but of these two options:

1. write the array from the disk every time the program is run
2. write the array once with a throwaway program so I can just copy the
       code of the array and have it be hardcoded

Two seems much more sensible. I just don't know how

Comment: Just read them - 151 files is going to take no noticeable amount of time at all.

Comment: write the array once and save records  .then read it when program start.but when folder modified you have to read again and update record.you can save record in a something like `xml`.and also you can use a background thread to find changes

Comment: What is your question exactly? "Please write my code for me?", or is it something more succinct?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The question is the last line... I don't know how to write the array into a `code` format that is literally array[][] = {"","",""}. I know how to write the code that will make an array I can use in my program at run time, but I just want some code I can put in my java file

Comment: @EvanKnowles okay, I had assumed that was bad practice, I will do that then, thx

Answer (score 0):

Check if there any previous record. If there are no records, write the array and save it. If there are records, read from it.